# How do I make pop-up info box appear next to mouse cursor?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg

I have info boxes that should display just above the mouse cursor when a state is hovered over. However, I can't seem to get the info box to listen - they keep appearing far to the right of the cursor.

I am a bit confused as I have used this code on a previous site without issue, but it is suddenly acting up for me here.

[image: Map with bad info box]

I've tried messing with the info box position as well as the map position.

```js
$("path, circle").hover(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display', 'block');
  $('#info-box').html($(this).data('info'));
});

$("path, circle").mouseleave(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('display', 'none');
});

$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $('#info-box').css('top', e.pageY - $('#info-box').height() - 30);
  $('#info-box').css('left', e.pageX - ($('#info-box').width()) / 2);
}).mouseover();

var ios = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;
if (ios) {
  $('a').on('click touchend', function() {
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    window.open(link, '_blank');
    return false;
  });
}
```

```css
#us-map {
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

path:hover,
circle:hover {
  stroke: #5A5A5A !important;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  fill: #5A5A5A !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#path67 {
  fill: none !important;
  stroke: #A9A9A9 !important;
  cursor: default;
}

#info-box {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #BF0A30;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<!-- your HTML here, please -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add your HTML as well. Also check your dev tools console for script errors.

Comment: @herrstrietzel Hello - I tried to add my HTML but because I am working with an SVG map, the code block was too large and an error occurred. I see the following in console: Refused to apply style from '--style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: You can reduce your map to only a few counties to reproduce the rror. Indeed the script seems to work see [codepen](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/QWzYJWe?editors=1010). Could it be your map or a wrapping div has transforms applied? If so it can cause offsets.

Comment: @herrstrietzel I don't believe so - that is what is confusing to me about all this. Here is my [codepen](https://codepen.io/bmo103/pen/OJrLKRy) where I originally took the code from. I used a "premade" svg as I am still fairly new to all of this, but you can see HTML, CSS, and JS all work well together here. I will mess with it some more and see if I get anywhere.

Comment: Please create a codepen reproducing your offset issue. It might be CSS rule causing the error or another script. Did your issue occur when changing the svg map?